# Why am I getting the following error with Apache Commons Daemon ( 'specified service does not exist' )?

Tags: apache-commons-daemon

I'm attempting to run Apache Commons Daemon tool (on Windows 7), and when I double-click on LoggerServicew.exe (which was originally prunmgr.exe in the Apache Deamons folder) , I am getting the following error message :

[image]

What is meant by "as an installed service" ?  How do I make this  an installed service ?

My directory :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See [Apache Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) - this details the exact usage.

Here is a quote from their page regarding installing a service:

> Prunsrv is a service application for running applications as services.
>   It can convert any application (not just Java applications) to run as
>   a service.
>
> Each command line directive is in the form of `//XX[//ServiceName]`. If
>   the `//ServiceName` parameter is omitted, then the service name is
>   assumed to be the name of the file.  For example if the application is
>   renamed as TestService.exe, then the default service name is
>   TestService. The available command line options are:
>
> ```
> //IS  Install service
> ```
>
> Starting with version 1.0.8 a more traditional command line can be
>   used in the form: `command [ServiceName]`.

Comment: is this your full answer though?

Comment: Added some more directions.